# How do I convert this SQL to Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I have this SQL

```
select product_id, date_booked, sum(quantity) from booking_hotelcheck where client_id=1 and status='Complete'
group by product_id, date_booked
```

and it returns :
[image]

and i try to convert it to django queryset:

```
>>> HotelCheck.objects.filter(client=1,status='Complete').values('product','date_booked','quantity').aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
{}
>>>
```

but it returns an empty set...

is my django queryset didn't convert my SQL?
can anyone can give me an idea on how can I convert my SQL to django queryset?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HotelCheck.objects.filter(client=1, status='Complete').values('product','date_booked').annotate(Sum('quantity'))
```